# Discord.py and youtube_dl: looking for video length before download

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So included within this online [script (Non-existent)](https://repl.it/@SUPERMECHM500/file), I am trying to find out the length of the video/audio that will be downloaded before it does. Notes are included within the script.

My question: How do I find the length of a video before it downloads as audio?

Please do not use or mention any part of repl.it. I use IDLE python 3.7.3, while this portion is located on a script on my PC to run my bot.

Sorry if I could not word this any better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to process data then download if video length is less or equal to a certain value:

```py
class AudioTooLongError(commands.CommandError): pass

@classmethod
async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    to_run = functools.partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=url, download=False)
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

    if 'entries' in data:
        # take first item from a playlist
        data = data['entries'][0]

    if data['duration'] > 3600:
        # Forbid downloading of sources more than 1 hour long.
        raise AudioTooLongError

    if not stream:
        try: data = ytdl.process_ie_result(data)
        except PermissionError: pass
        source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)
    return data['url']
```

Try this!

Comment: Yes, it worked. in the data['duration'], what unit is that number (how many of those make a second)?

Comment: These are just regular seconds.

Comment: I was trying it out, and when I did search something 10 hours, it didn't play it, but it did download it and only then did my bot say to try another search term. I used a try/except block. I have to delete these files myself.